# What to do about cut feeder roots when moving bush

Tags: transplanting, currant

I moved 2year old black currant day ago, having cut feeder roots.  It occurred to me that perhaps i should have capped or disinfected root ends?  Soil is sandy, well drained, temperature is around 15c day, 0-2c night time (quebec).
Bush seems to be ok after move but i am worried about infection.  Should i do something about root ends?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, treatment is not necessary. The only caution is to make sure that large roots are cut cleanly to present as small a surface area as possible to prevent infection possibility. If the digging spade used to cut the roots was reasonably sharp then that is usually enough. Black currant is known for its ability to generate roots readily so the recovery should be quite quick.